# Web deployment IIS - The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Tags: visual-studio, iis

I published a web app created in Visual Studio using IIS. My problem starts when I want to share a directory browsing from my folder. Then its working fine until I realized when I published, the files(eg : If I change Label.Text, its not updated) of my web application is not updated.

So I created new web application to test whether my method or publish profile is wrong. Unfortunately, every new project I published I got "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden : The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory."

So I think there's something wrong with my IIS, so I reinstall IIS but nothing happens. I also make a lot of work by search existing solution to this problem but nothing works.

I look up at  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myweb , and only see web.config file, there's no other file like aspx, html, asset folder or etc. I don't want to show directory browsing when open my web, I want to show the design aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **repaired my Visual Studio 2017** using Visual Studio Installer, then I **uninstall Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform** by go to Manage NuGet Package as I getting Compilation Error during publishing.